# htaccess redirect whole url as parameter

Tags: .htaccess

We have created an iframe loader index5.php which will show two iframes, iframe1 and iframe2. The content of iframe2 can be set by accessing index5.php?url=iframe2url. So, going to

```
domain/index5.php?url=www.serverfault.com
```

would load serverfault in one iframe and our code in another. We only want to be able to use this on our own domain to prevent XSS, so we've made sure the index5.php only allows our domain.

We furthermore want to redict all requests to our wordpress website from

```
domain/page
```

to

```
domain/index5.php?url=http://domain/page
```

However, if we use

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index5\.php$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain/index5.php?url=http://domain/$1 [R=301,L]
```

there is an infinite redirect. How can we prevent this?

Answer (score 2):

When you do a rewrite in a `.htaccess` file (as opposed to within the apache configuration), the the path prefix of the directory containing the file is stripped away, as per [the apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/intro.html#htaccess).

This means that the rewrite condition should not contain the leading `/`. Instead, it should read

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^index5\.php$
```

Comment: Thanks, but this still doesn't work. What I did was add an extra parameter to the URL in de index5.php so we can prevent rewriting, namely &qcrd=1. 
This is the current code: 


    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^qcrd$
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain/index5.php?url=http://domain/$
1 [R=301,L]

which does not infinetly redirect anymore, but now the $1 only uses the subdir. How can I use the full URL in the rewrite rule?

Comment: It's impossible to read your code in a comment. Please add it to the question instead.